# Fantastico pros and cons

Tags: hosting, installation

I am working with someone that has a host (internetplanners.com) that uses fantastico to install WordPress.

Basically, my question is has anyone had bad experiences with fantastico or webhost internetplanners.com?

*Note, I have installed Wordpress on my local machine (Windows) and didn't have any trouble.  I don't have experience installing on a hosting service manually but think I could do it needed.*

Since I wasn't familiar with fantastico one-click install, I did a search and found 2 links about reasons not to use fantastico:

http://www.howtospoter.com/web-20/wordpress/3-reasons-not-to-use-fantastico-for-wordpress 
1) simplicity = false security (if upgrade breaks, it can be difficult to fix); 2) upgrade doesn't put in maintenance mode or back up database, 3) upgrade doesn't deactivate plug ins.

from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/installing-from-justhost :
I agree with ZGani. Fantastico doesn't upgrade the third party scripts version frequently. So you have to wait for Fantastico upgrade to get latest version of WordPress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always thought that Fantastico essentially just;

1. Placed a copy of WordPress on your server (not always the latest version, as you say, this is a local copy limited by the update frequency of Fantastico)
2. Set-up a database (and user) automatically
3. Configured `wp-config.php` accordingly

Then you'd just continue to use WordPress for maintenance as you would normally.

In the past, I've worked on WP sites that were set-up with it, and don't recall any issues updating it.

Personally, being a geek, I always run a manual install. Just feels cleaner, plus I know I'm always starting with the latest and greatest version.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosts bundle a bunch of plugins with their Fantastico installs. Several of them now include Jetpack in the bundle, and occasionally a host will include a bunch of other stuff you probably don't want. Its not a problem to delete the extra junk you don't want after running the install script. And you're under no obligation to use Fantastico to actually manage upgrades - WP core does that just fine.

The only bad experience I had with one-click installs was on a host (Network Solutions) who had been seriously hacked. The WordPress install that was built through the one-click process was all kinds of corrupted - had sneaky eval()'d code in it and everything. Wiping the install and uploading a fresh core, and changing db passwords fixed that - but it isn't something I'd want to go through again.

Comment: Thanks -- I ended up trying with Fantastico and it looks good.